# PowerShellでAdd-TypeでC#のコードを指定しています．Linuxで動かすには？

Tags: c#, linux, powershell

## 要旨

### 現在やっていること

WindowsのPowerShellで、ユーザーのクライアントソリューションを開発しています．特に問題なく動いているのですが、やはりユーザー側からクラウドベースに載せたい旨のリクエストがありました．クラウドのプラットフォームはLinuxになる見込みです．

### 教えていただきたいこと

現在のシェルスクリプトでは

- Javaを起動しJavaベースのXSLTプロセッサを動かす．
- Windowsアプリケーションの.exeを動かす

を順に組み合わせていくつかのステップで行っています．
ここで、

- 起動している側のプログラムの標準出力、エラー出力をリアルタイムで取得したい
- エラーだったらそこで終了させるため、各ステップの戻り値を得たい

の必要があるため、次のようなC#のコードをAdd-Typeして各ステップのプログラム起動の際に使用しています．Windowsだと.NETが標準でついてくるので（Visual Studioなしでも）C#のコンパイルと実行が可能です．

これをLinuxで行いたいのですが ①そもそもLinuxのPowerShellからでC#をコンパイル/実行可能であるか？ ②実行するにはどのような準備・設定が必要であるか？を教えていただきたいです．

LinuxにおけるPowerShellとか、.NETのLinuxでのディストリビューションとか話だけは伺っていますが、何分にもすぐ試せる環境がありません．

## 該当する.ps1の記述

### メインの.ps1

```
Import-Module "$($PSScriptRoot)/module" -Variable 'procTools'
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $procTools -Language CSharp
```

### module/module.psm1

```
# C# codes for executing process
# Standard output & error output from process are captured by the handler and asynchronously outputted by Console.WriteLine.
$procTools = @"

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Proc.Tools
{
  public static class exec
  {
    public static int runCommand(string executable, string args = "", string cwd = "", string verb = "runas") {

      //* Create your Process
      Process process = new Process();
      process.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
      process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

      //* Optional process configuration
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args)) { process.StartInfo.Arguments = args; }
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cwd)) { process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = cwd; }
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(verb)) { process.StartInfo.Verb = verb; }

      //* Set your output and error (asynchronous) handlers
      process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
      process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);

      //* Start process and handlers
      process.Start();
      process.BeginOutputReadLine();
      process.BeginErrorReadLine();
      process.WaitForExit();

      //* Return the commands exit code
      return process.ExitCode;
    }
    public static void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) {
      //* Do your stuff with the output (write to console/log/StringBuilder)
      Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
    }
  }
}
"@
```

### Add-Typeしたクラスのメソッドの実行（例）

```
$ret = [Proc.Tools.exec]::runCommand($java_exec, $java_cmd_param);
Write-Host 'XSLT processing return code:' $ret  -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor Black
if ($ret -ne 0) {exit}
```

## その他要件

### PowerShellのバージョン

```
PS D:\My_Documents> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
 7      2      6
```

### Windowsアプリケーションの.exe

このアプリケーションにはLinux版があるので、クラウドに移行した場合はそちらを使用します．

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

## 追記

### 想定される　Linuxのディストリビューションとバージョン

現時点ではまだクライアントソリューションの開発中です．お客さまからは特にLinuxのディストリビューション、バージョンなどは示されず、「クラウドのLinux稼働環境で」動かせるか？と打診されている状態です．残念ながらまだ大まかな話です．

Comment: 念のため、Linux の種類 (ディストリビューション) やバージョン等の情報も記載しておいた方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: こんな記事[任意のLinuxディストリビューションへ、.NET (.NET Core)とPowerShellをインストールする](https://impsbl.hatenablog.jp/entry/InstallDotNetAndPowerShell)では大概大丈夫らしいですし公式情報もあります[Linux に .NET をインストールする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/install/linux), [Linux に PowerShell をインストールする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.2), [Windows 以外のプラットフォームでの PowerShell の相違点](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/whats-new/unix-support?view=powershell-7.2), [dotnet build](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)

Comment: ディストリビューションやバージョンについては現時点では特定できない旨追記いたしました．Linuxへ.NETをインストールする記事は見させていただきました．SDKをセットアップできるなら、上記のPoweShellも行けそうですね．.NETとPowerScriptは各々パッケージがあって混乱しておりましたが、何とか時間（とマシン）を取って試してみたいと思います．どうもアドバイスをありがとうございます．